# Asynchronous Ajax save from a modal with no page refresh Laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Using Laravel 5.2.45

I have a database set up with a few tables, like "users", "categories" and "contacts".

An User can create a contact and attribute some category to it.

In the `contacts table`, I have this schema:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('contacts', function (Blueprint $table) 
        {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

            $table->integer('id')->unsigned()->autoIncrement();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();            
            $table->string('image');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('lastname');
            $table->string('email', 191);
            $table->string('phone',191);
            $table->string('address');
            $table->string('description', 255);
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();

        });

        Schema::table('contacts', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');

        });
    }
```

Note there is a column that fetches the ID of the category you choose for your contact.

This is the schema for the `categories` table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) 
        {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

            $table->integer('id')->unsigned()->autoIncrement();
            $table->string('category')->required()->unique()->index();
        });
    }
```

To enter the attributes in the contacts table, I have the following in the `ContactsController` controller:

```
public function create(CreateContactRequest $request)
    {
        $contact                = new Contact;            
        $contact-> name         = $request->get('name');
        $contact-> lastname     = $request->get('lastname');
        $contact-> email        = $request->get('email');
        $contact-> phone        = $request->get('phone');
        $contact-> address      = $request->get('address');
        $contact-> description  = $request->get('description');
        $contact-> user_id      = \Auth::user()->id;
        $contact-> category_id  = $request->get('category');
        // $contact-> category     = $request->get('category');

        // Checking if input has a file
        if ($request->hasFile('image')) 
        {            
            // It does, so set name to a random string with 10 chars
            $fileName = str_random(10);

            // Get the extension of the file (.jpg, .png...)
            $fileName .= '.' . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();

            // Move the file to the storage
            $request->file('image')->move(storage_path('app/public/uploads'), $fileName);

            $contact->image = $fileName;
        }

        $contact->save();

        $contacts = App\Contact::where('user_id', \Auth::user()->id)->get();
        return redirect(route('contacts', compact('contacts')));
    }
```

In the end, you'll get redirected to the `contacts` view, where you'll simply see the `contacts` table with all columns.

The form to enter the contact is like this:

```
Contact Form
**Basically, inputs for the columns name, lastname, email, phone, address and description.** 

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h2 class="panel-title"> Contact Form </h2>
            </div>
            {!! Form::open(['route' => ['contacts.create'], 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('category', 'Choose Your Contact Category') !!}
                                <fieldset>
                                    <select name="category" class="form-control" id="category">
                                        <option disabled="true" selected="true">
                                            List
                                        </option>                            
                                        @foreach ($categories as $category)
                                            <option name="category" id="category" class="category" value="{!! $category->id !!}">
                                                {!! $category->category !!}
                                            </option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                            <label>
                                Create Your Contact Category
                            </label><br/>
                            <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#demo-default-modal">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Create New Category
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class = "form-group
                                @if($errors->has('name'))
                                    has-error
                                @endif"> 
                                {!! Form::label('name', 'Name *') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('name', old('name'),['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Name of your contact']) !!}
                                @if($errors->has('name')) 
                                    <p class = "help-block"><span class="label label-danger">Warning</span> {{ $errors->first('name') }}</p>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class = "form-group 
                                @if($errors->has('lastname'))
                                    has-error
                                @endif"> 
                                {!! Form::label('lastname', 'Lastname') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('lastname', old('lastname'),['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Lastname of your contact']) !!}                
                                @if($errors->has('lastname'))
                                    <p class = "help-block"><span class="label label-danger">Warning</span> {{ $errors->first('lastname') }}</p>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class = "form-group 
                                @if($errors->has('email'))
                                    has-error
                                @endif">
                                {!! Form::label('email', 'E-Mail *') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('email', null,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'If your contact does not have one use contactName@email.com']) !!}
                                @if($errors->has('email'))
                                    <p class = "help-block"><span class="label label-danger">Warning</span> {{ $errors->first('email') }}</p>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class = "form-group
                                @if($errors->has('phone'))
                                    has-error
                                @endif">
                                {!! Form::label('phone', 'Phone Number *') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('phone', null,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'If your contact does not have one, just insert three numbers at random']) !!}
                                @if($errors->has('phone'))
                                    <p class="help-block"><span class="label label-danger">Warning</span> {{ $errors->first('phone') }}</p>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class = "form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('address', 'Address') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('address', old('address'),['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Street name, number, neighborhood, city, state initials, country']) !!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class = "form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('description', 'Description') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('description', old('description'),['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Something to describe your contact. Use a simple word, like family, work, friend and such']) !!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class = "form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('image', 'Upload an image!') !!}
                                {!! Form::file('image')!!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
                            <p class="text-left">
                                <strong> * = Required field (Can't be blank) </strong>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer text-right">
                    <div class = "btn">
                        {!! Form::button(' Submit Information', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary fa fa-plus-circle']) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please note that the category is inserted from a dropdown `select` tag, where the options are permeated using `option` tags.

If you need to create a new category for your contact, you press the `Create Category` button, which loads a modal with a form to create your category.

```
**Modal for category**

<div class="modal fade demo-default-modal" name="demo-default-modal" id="demo-default-modal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="demo-default-modal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">
                    Create Category
                </h3>
            </div>

            {!! Form::open(['route'=>['category.create'], 'method'=>'POST', 'class'=>'modalForm', 'id'=>'modalForm', 'name'=>'modalForm']) !!}
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('category', 'Category') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('category', NULL, ['placeholder'=>'Category Name', 'class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    {!! Form::button('Close', ['type' => 'button', 'class' => 'btn btn-default', 'data-dismiss'=>'modal']) !!}
                    {!! Form::submit('Save Category', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary modalSave', 'name' => 'modalSave', 'id' => 'modalSave']) !!}
                </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When you insert the category name and click the `Save Category` button, the form will go through the route setup as:

```
Route::post('category/create', [
    'as'=>'category.create', 'uses'=>'CategoryController@create', 'redirects'=>'phonebook', 'with'=>'input'
]);
```

The route calls the parameters at the `CategoryController`'s method `create`, which is:

```
public function create(CreateCategoryRequest $request)
    {
        $category           = new Category;
        $category->category = $request->get('category');

        $category->save();

        return redirect('phonebook');
    }
```

Everything so far is working fine, no errors are thrown.

The contact is inserted in the right table with the right inputs, even with the category id, which, by the way, is created in the `categories` table without any problem as well.

But the thing is, I want to create the category from the modal, but WITHOUT refreshing the page, because let's imagine an user is creating the contact, permeating all input fields and letting the category select for last.

And imagine this user has to create the category for his contact. He'll pop up the modal, input something and click the send button, which will redirect him to the form, but WITHOUT all of his inputs.

Note that in the route for the category creation, I tried to pass the parameter to keep the inputs, but it didn't happened.

**MAYBE IMPORTANT**

My view is set up using the `@include` syntax provided by Laravel, so it looks like this

**INSERT CONTACT VIEW**

```
phonebook.blade.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <script src="/js/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/modalSaver.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/laroute.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/nifty.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootbox.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ui-modals.js"></script>

        <link href="{{URL::asset('docs/nifty-v2.4/demo/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{{URL::asset('docs/nifty-v2.4/demo/css/nifty.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{{URL::asset('docs/nifty-v2.4/demo/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('css/infost.css')}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('css/header.css')}}">

        <title> 
            Phonebook - Add a new contact
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>        
        @include('partials.header')

        @if(Auth::check())
            <br/><br/>
            @include('partials.contactForm')
        @else
            @include('partials.info')
        @endif
    </body>
</html>
```

The `partials.contactForm` partial is where the form to input the contact info and the modal bit are located.

SO I tried AJAX, and, being new to this, I couldn't work something.

Also, note that I have `jquery-2.2.1` in a minified file.

These are my tries, which, by the way, are in a separate `.js` file (`modalSaver.js`) from the view:

```
**function 1**

var $form = $("#demo-default-modal");

$form.submit(function(e)
{
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'category.create',
        data: $form.serialize(),
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});




**function 2**

var form = 'demo-default-modal';

$("form").submit(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault()
    {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'category.create',
            data: $form.serialize(),
        });
    }
});



**function 3**

$('form.modalForm').submit(function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post($(this).attr("action"),
    $(this).serialize(),
    function(info)
    {
        $("#result").html(info);
    });
});
```

As stated before, none of these functions seemed to work.

Here is my question, **finally** (sorry for the long post, but I tried to be really meticulous about it):

How to make an AJAX function to save the category in my database, in the `categories` table, show the category I just inserted listed in the dropdown `select` tag list, located in the form, and do all of this without refreshing the page, but simply hiding the modal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To be honest, this was really long to read. You're a lot more likely to get a good response with a specific shorter question. Either way, first, even with a  page refresh you should be able to catch all the old inputs with Laravel. Laravel has a built-in function for that. Second, what you need is reactivity, it sounds like. Check out http://vuecasts.com .

Comment: @Chris I was just trying to be really meticulous about the code, because I was already frustrated with this bit and maybe the error was going to be something so simple in a little bit of code in a hiding corner of the files, that I thought about posting everything that was related to it, so I did. Also, I was going to stay away from my source code for a while, so if anyone asked to post something code-wise, I wasn't gonna be able to. But I get what you are saying, and I will take it into consideration. Also, I should have started the post with the question already. Thank you anyway, really. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the create category controller to `return $category` instead return redirect.

than change your ajax script to this

```js
$('#modalForm').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $form = $(this);

  // get url from action attribute
  var $url = $(this).attr('action');

  $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: $url,
      data: $form.serialize(),
    })
    .done(function(res) {
      // make new option based on ajax response
      var option = '<option class="category" value="' + res.id + '">' + res.category + '</option>';

      // append option to catogory select
      $('#category').append(option);
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for going through this gigantic post, man. 
Your code snippet works and I am really thankful. 

I tried changing my Ajax for something like this already, except for a line or two, but it didn't work so I didn't care about saving the code and all. I had totally forgot about the append() bit, which is one of the things I had forgot.

Again, thank you.

Comment: Just the bit of getting the right ID is returning an error. How can I fix that? I checked the appended option tag html, and the value is set as undefined. It just retrieves the right ID value when I refresh the page.

Comment: @G.Felicio try to console.log the ajax response. what is the result?

Comment: In my console I have "jquery-2.2.1.min.js:4 XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:8000/category/create"". The category is created in the database without a problem, with the ID and name, but the value is returning as "undefined" in the "value=ID" located in the option tag. And is returning a "500" error when I try to create a contact right away, because the ID of the category is undefined. But if I refresh the form page, everything works fine.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I want to know the ajax response when create category. add `console.log(res)` inside `done` callback before `var option`

Comment: This is what returns:



"Object {category: "abc"}
   category: "abc"
      __proto__: Objectconstructor(.....)"



There are a lot of other options/menus/collapsed menus after the (.....) bit.

Comment: no id in that object? it should return the id too. or maybe you can return all categories using `return Category::all()` and replace all category option.

Comment: Found the error. In my Category model I had public $incrementing = false;( don't remember why), so, I guess, that at a first moment the create method in my CategoryController didn't set the ID field. Or, most likely, I couldn't retrieve it. But everything else worked just fine. Thank you, again, for your help.